# Hibernate Many-To-One using other schema on DB2

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I am using hibernate-annotation (entitymanager) to handle my db2 databases using separate schema.

My main schema is called "mainschema". It has a table for fileuploads.

Then I have some other schema (schema1, schema2, schema3, schemaN).

How can I tell the many-to-one relationship on the schemaN to refer to the filetable on "mainschema". If I open the connection, I tell which schema to use. But the many-to-one is still using that schema and the fileupload table is only available in the "mainschema"

Thanks for help!

EDIT:

My fileupload hibernate bean using explicit the main schema:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOKUMENT", schema="mainschema")
```

Then I have one schema for every client, have a look at here:
The Schema is not set in the bean. It is set instead in time where the connection is opened.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SOMETABLE")
```

This table "SOMETABLE" is existing in every schema for every client.
It refers to the dokument entity with an many-to-one

```
@Many-To-One
@JoinColumn(name="DOKUMENT_ID")
public Dokument getDokument() { return dokument }
public void setDokument() { this.dokument = dokument }
```

Question can be closed. It is working without any changes, because hibernate is still using "mainschema" automaticly.

Comment: the Many-To-One relationship is from mainschema(one) to schema1... scheman(many)? or the other way around?

Comment: the other way from schemaN to the mainschema.

Comment: have a look at my edit. but thanks for your awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to map SchemaN to MainSchema one-to-many

```
@Entity
public class SchemaN{

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=MainSchema.class, mappedBy="pk_SchemaN")
    private List<MainSchema> ms;

...

}

@Entity
public class MainSchema{

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="FK_MainSchema")
     private SchemaN pk_schemaN;

...

}
```

Hope this helps you it should be the same for any Schema1 to N